# 2017 VW Passat is showing 255km/h when stationary on VVS

Tags: vw, vehicle-speed-sensor

I don't have a lot of tools to get deep into it. But yesterday I started my car at work. Idled for 10 minutes and then drove out of the parking spot kind of fast, drove home using cruise control on the highway. Later the same day I tried to start the car and it just kind of clicks. I received this error on the dash. And after hooking up my OBD2 I found out that the VVS is reading 255 when stationary. I believe the issue is in a wheel sensor but don't know how to check. Any advice would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Can you share ALL the stored error codes?

Comment: So I've solved the issue. And it was very simple. Bad battery cell. The battery would read over 12 volts on the voltmeter, but when cranking, it dropped all the way down to 3V. I was working solo so couldn't crank and check voltage at the same time. Once my dad got home I figured it out pretty quick.